# When comparing two files, how can I get the exact line number of changed locations?

Tags: diff

I need to compare two source files and obtain the exact line number of changed statements. I used GNU diff and output in a unified format. However, this output only shows the changed chunk (identified by line ranges). But what I really want is some tool that can directly give me this:

(about the new file)

```
line 5: added;
line 11: modified
```

(about the old file)

```
line 7: deleted
```

Is there any tool that can achieve this? Or is there any option in GNU diff that can achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I thought diff told you what lines were inserted or deleted as ranges.   Is that hard to convert into an individual list of lines inserted or deleted?

Comment: Actually it's not hard ... I just did that: simply parsing the diff text inside "@@ @@", which gives the starting line # and its range. Thanks Ira!

Answer (score 0):

Graphical tools like [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) or [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) show both files with line numbers. Maybe it is what your are looking for.